# How to pass a table-valued parameter from a stored procedure to C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

How to pass a table-valued parameter from a stored procedure to C#?

Comment: TVP's are readonly and input-only - you can pass them **into** a stored procedure - but not the other way around (at this time)